# Correct interpretation of this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

I was given the following problem:

> Decide if the following subsets of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ of functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are linearly independent: $$A = \{1, \sin, \cos\}$$ $$B=\{1, \sin^2, \cos^2\}$$

I am confused as to whether $\sin, \cos$ are expected to take the same argument or not. For example, for set $A$, should I evaluate for non-trivial solutions of

$$\lambda_1(1)+ \lambda_2\sin x + \lambda_3 \cos x = 0$$

or

$$\lambda_1(1)+ \lambda_2\sin x + \lambda_3 \cos y = 0$$

Thanks.

Comment: The argument is certainly the same. If it wasn't, I am sure it would be given more attention in the statement of the problem. Writing just $\sin$ is rather informal and should indicate some trivial usage of the sine. Also, your argument doesn't have to be continuous, so that would allow you _too much_. You could construct such a discontinuous argument to make pretty much any three functions linearly dependent.

Comment: And should I prove they are linearly dependent for some $x$ or for all $x$? $A$ is certainly linearly dependent for $x = \pi/2$; $B$ is linearly dependent for any $x$ by letting $\lambda_1 = -1$ and $\lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = 1$.

Comment: It is not for just some $x$. That $x$ is nothing in context of your functions. Your functions are vectors. You can add them and you can scale them. That means that they are vectors. That $x$ is just something you use to help yourself define the functions. There is no some intrinsic property of a function named "argument". Formally, $\sin(x)$ is not a function. Functions are mappings. And to state a mapping you need to state what maps to what. So $x\mapsto\sin(x)$ is a proper defintion of a function. Then $\sin(x)$ is just assumed to mean this previous defintion. Does this make it clearer?

Comment: Absolutely clear. Worth to be made an answer, even. Thank you so much!

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that your question was closed :( But still, I don't think I could be helpful a lot. What I think the best thing I can do for you is to give you an advice to seek some deeper and higher mathematics to clarify some simple things. So in this example, while you are learning about some exotic vector spaces, take a look at formal, set-theoretic definition of a mapping, relations and functions. Then take a look at some simple finctional analysis. You will get the spirit of how they handle and understand functions in these contextes. So in general...

Comment: Don't bw afraid to read something too complex, you don't need to understand it. It is enough to just get some touristic experience and see how things will unravel in the future of your studies. That experience will be a valuable guide while you learn basic concepts at your pace. You have seen enough to understand how to handle functions in the most fundamental scenarios. You felt how they work. Now see some more exotic scenarios and they will be even clearer to you. So, formal definition, then functional analysis, then come back to your question and you will solve it.

Comment: Oh lol, you said it was worth an answer haha, I read would I want to answer lol, sorry... Anyway, I still hope you won't find this tiny advice a complete nonsense :D